# Azure ARM template prefix each value in array parameter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In a `scheduledQueryRules` element we are passing the `aznsAction.actionGroup` (array) from a parameter file.

The parameter looks like this:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "actionGroups": {
            "value": [
                "ActionGroupName1",
                "ActionGroupName2",
                "ActionGroupName3",
                "ActionGroupName4"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and we pass it to the ARM template like this:

```json
...
"action": {
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
    "severity": "[variables('alertActions').SeverityLevel]",
    "aznsAction": {
        "actionGroup": "[array(parameters('actionGroups'))]"
    },
    "trigger": {
        "thresholdOperator": "[variables('alertTrigger').Operator]",
        "threshold": "[variables('alertTrigger').Threshold]"
    }
}
...
```

The ActionGroups should be selected by using `resourceId(..)` functions, however parameter files do not support this.
The deployment is working fine when we replace the `actionGroups` value with the fully written resource paths, like this:

```json
"actionGroups": {
    "value": [
        "/subscriptions/{id}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/ActionGroupName1",
        "/subscriptions/{id}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/ActionGroupName2",
        "/subscriptions/{id}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/ActionGroupName3",
        "/subscriptions/{id}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/ActionGroupName4"
        ]
    }
```

But since I do not want to hardcode the subscription and resourceGroup I'm looking for a solution where we can prefix the individual array values before passing it to the `aznsAction.actionGroup`.

I don't think it is possible to use `copy` here.

Basically I would like something like this:

```json
"aznsAction": {
    "actionGroup": "[select[array(parameters('actionGroups'))], concat(resourceId(..), parameters('actionGroups')[iterator()])]"
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: You mentioned that you don't want to hardcode the sub/rg values - how are you determining what they are?

Comment: @bmoore-msft using `resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/ActionGroups/ActionGroupName1')`

Comment: Cool - looks like Thomas got it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you have a parameter containing the action group names like that:

```
"parameters": {
  "actionGroups": {
    "type": "array",
    "value": [
      "ActionGroupName1",
      "ActionGroupName2",
      "ActionGroupName3",
      "ActionGroupName4"
    ]
  }
}
```

You could create a variable to transform the array into an array of action group ids:

```
"variables": {
  "copy": [
    {
      "name": "actionGroupIds",
      "count": "[length(parameters('actionGroups'))]",
      "input": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/ActionGroups', parameters('actionGroups')[copyIndex('actionGroupIds')])]"
    }
  ]
}
```

then you can use it like that:

```
"aznsAction": {
    "actionGroup": "[variables('actionGroupIds')]"
}
```